# pr2controller tutorial, quaternion not the same for same program in python and cpp

Tags: ros, python, c++, quaternion, tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just went through [pr2_controllers/Tutorials/Moving the arm through a Cartesian pose trajectory](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_controllers/Tutorials/Moving%20the%20arm%20through%20a%20Cartesian%20pose%20trajectory).

I tried to rewrite the client program from python to cpp. The program worked but got different quaternion vector(x,y,z,w) with the result from the original program.

The original code snippet from the tutorial:

```
#pretty-print list to string
def pplist(list):
  return ' '.join(['%2.3f'%x for x in list])

#print out the positions, velocities, and efforts of the right arm joints
if __name__ == "__main__":
rospy.init_node("test_cartesian_ik_trajectory_executer")
tf_listener = tf.TransformListener()
time.sleep(.5) #give the transform listener time to get some frames

# not needed, fix tutorial
joint_names = ["r_shoulder_pan_joint",
               "r_shoulder_lift_joint",
               "r_upper_arm_roll_joint",
               "r_elbow_flex_joint",
               "r_forearm_roll_joint",
               "r_wrist_flex_joint",
               "r_wrist_roll_joint"]

positions = [[.76, -.19, .83], [0.59, -0.36, 0.93]]
orientations = [[.02, -.09, 0.0, 1.0], [0.65, -0.21, .38, .62]]

success = call_execute_cartesian_ik_trajectory("/base_link", \
        positions, orientations)

#check the final pose
(trans, rot) = tf_listener.lookupTransform('base_link', 'r_wrist_roll_link', rospy.Time(0))
print "end Cartesian pose: trans", pplist(trans), "rot", pplist(rot)
```

The result pose is

```
 end Cartesian pose: trans 0.590 -0.360 0.930 rot 0.651 -0.211 0.381 0.621
```

which agrees with the result by doing `rosrun tf tf_echo base_link r_wrist_roll_link`

But the result of my program is

```
 end Cartesian pose: trans,0.59,-0.36,0.93,rol,0.83,-0.27,0.49,0.00
```

Here is the code snippet:

```
   tf::TransformListener listener;
   ros::NodeHandle node;

   ROS_INFO("Now calling the client function...");
   success = call_execute_cartesian_ik_trajectory(node, "base_link", position, orientations);

   ROS_INFO("Finished calling");
   tf::StampedTransform transform;
   try{
      listener.lookupTransform("base_link", "r_wrist_roll_link", 
                           ros::Time(0), transform);
   }   
   catch (tf::TransformException ex){
      ROS_ERROR("%s",ex.what());
   }   

   ROS_INFO("end Cartesian pose: trans,%3.2f,%3.2f,%3.2f,rol,%3.2f,%3.2f,%3.2f,%3.2f \n ", transform.getOrigin().x(),transform.getOrigin().y(),transform.getOrigin().z(),transform.getRotation().getAxis().x(),transform.getRotation().getAxis().y(),transform.getRotation().getAxis().z(),transform.getRotation().getAxis().w());
```

I guess the error lies in misuse of the function `transform.getRotation().getAxis().x()`

Can someone point out what went wrong? Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10851/pr2controller-tutorial,-quaternion-not-the-same-for-same-program-in-python-and-cpp/) by [vincent](https://answers.ros.org/users/280/vincent/) on ROS Answers with karma: 311 on 2011-08-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vincent](https://answers.ros.org/users/280/vincent/) on 2011-08-08**:
thanks for the info. And thank tfoote for editing.

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-08-08**:
Also keep in mind that "Closed" is used when admins/mods mark a question as a duplicate, offtopic, offensive, etc and technically doesn't mean the same thing as "Answered".

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-08-08**:
To mark a question as "Closed", please make sure that the correct answer is marked as "accepted". That is the green checkmark next to it (this question already has an accepted answer). There is no need to add a [Closed] to the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is definitely wrong is as you suspected the use of getAxis.

I think the python code puts out the raw quaternion.

In c++ you use getAxis(). First, to get the rotation, you should use getAngle() (you output the non-existent w component of the axis, that is zero). This will print out the rotation axis and angle correctly.

However, a quaternion represents axis and angle, but it is not exactly xyz=axis and w=angle. Usually w is cos(angle/2) and the axis is scaled to give a unit quaternion.
If you look at your output the python and c++ axes seem to be collinear, just differently scaled.

To get comparable outputs in c++ just use x(), y(),... to output the raw quaternion instead of getAxis.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-08-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vincent](https://answers.ros.org/users/280/vincent/) on 2011-08-08**:
haha, i made simple things complicated, thank you:)

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-08-08**:
There should also be w() directly.

**Comment by [vincent](https://answers.ros.org/users/280/vincent/) on 2011-08-08**:
exactly like what you said, getAxis() gives the unit axis vector. changed to x(),y(),z(),cos(0.5*getAngle()), worked! Thanks